# Is a list comprehension or a sequential filter more optimized?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, list-comprehension, computation-theory

Let's say you have to return the sum of all the multiples of 2 and 3 in a set of integers from 1-100. In Haskell, the code I would write would look something like this:

```
sum ([x*2 | x<-[1..100], x*2 < 100] `union` [x*3 | x<-[1..100], x*3 < 100])
```

This uses 2 list comprehensions with a union. Another solution would be to step through each item in the list and evaluate it (using a modulus), then add it to a separate list, which you would later add together.

Both of these solutions come out with the same answer, but which one is more optimized if you had to do the same for, say, a list from 1..1000000?

The answer to the original question is 3317 if you want to create your own algorithm.

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, why not use `takeWhile` instead of `filter`?

Comment: You seem to be asking which version is faster if you run them with a large n. Rather than speculate, why not just run the programs and see which one comes out faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for performance, you can simplify this problem to the point where you don't even need a computer....

Numbers divisible by 2 or 3 fall into a pattern

```
0 (1) 2 3 4 (5).... 6 (7) 8 9 10 (11).... etc
or
TFTTTF.... TFTTTF....
```

Assume that the max bound is divisible by 6, (if not, you can just choose the highest value below the real bound and add the remaining few values by hand).  Let `maxBound=6*N`.

For each additional N, you add the following values

```
6*n, 0, 6*n+2, 6*n+3, 6*n+4, 0
which sums to
24*n+9
```

so all you need to do is sum up

```
sum from n=0 to N of (24*n+9)
=24*(sum from n=0 to N of n) + 9*N
=24*N*(N-1)/2 + 9*N
=12*N^2-3*N
```

so a very fast Haskell program that would solve this problem would look something like this

```
f maxBound = 12*n^2-3*n + remainingStuff
                where n = maxBound `quot` 6
                      remainingStuff = sum $ filter (<= maxBound) [6*n, 6*n+2, 6*n+3, 6*n+4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `union` function is a "quadratic" algorithm, so using one list comprehension will be faster.

A better way which is useful for generating these kinds of sequences is to take advantage of the fact that they are ordered and merge them together with a function like:

```
merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge as [] = as
merge [] bs = bs
merge as@(a:at) bs@(b:bt) =
  case compare a b of
    LT -> a : merge at bs
    EQ -> a : merge at bt
    GT -> b : merge as bt
```

and then generate your sequence with:

```
[ x | x <- merge [2,4..100] [3,6..100] ]
```

One last tip for writing combinatorial loops... replace expressions like `x <- [1..100], 2*x < 100` with `x <- [1..49]`, or if you can't compute the upper bound explicitly, use `x <- takeWhile (\x -> 2*x < 100) [1..100]`. The latter forms only generates as many items as needed.